# Can I boot an Intel Mac from a USB drive?

Tags: mac, usb, boot

Can I boot an Intel Mac from a USB drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can, but I have never tried it... I'd post this as a comment but I don't have enough rep yet so I'd recommend you [this Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1948). Sorry I couldn't help more :)

Comment: Naw, that’s grand old stuff, nice one.